# Java: Why isn't String.format() working on this Long variable?

Tags: java

I am simply trying to get milliseconds to display the first two digits of the variable.

What I expect to work (I see two digits initially, then as it is incremented I see three digits):

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    Long milliSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(elapsedTime) % 1000;
    Long seconds = (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(elapsedTime));
    return String.format("%2d.%02d seconds", seconds, milliSeconds);
}
```

What actually works:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String milliSeconds = String.format("%02d",
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(elapsedTime) % 1000).substring(0, 2);
    Long seconds = (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(elapsedTime));
    return String.format("%2d.%s seconds", seconds, milliSeconds);
}
```

Or:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    double milliSeconds = (double)(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(elapsedTime) % 1000) / 1000;
    Long seconds = (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(elapsedTime));
    return String.format("%.2f seconds", seconds + milliSeconds);
}
```

I guess my first question would be **are either of my solutions that work more resource intensive than the one that doesn't?**  And secondly, what am I doing wrong in the first solution?  I would expect `%02d` to take the long and truncate it to 2 digits buffered with a 0.  Instead I see the two digits plus a trailing 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.out.printf("%07.3f seconds", (elapsedTime / 1000f));
```

Comment: Thanks, elapsedTime was a `Long` but this works: `return String.format("%.2f seconds", (float)elapsedTime / 1000f);`

Comment: If one of the operands is a floating point and the other is an integer then the result will be a floating point.  The literal on the `1000` will define it as a `float`, there is also `d` and `l` for `double` and `long`.

Answer (score 2):

milliseconds should be `%03d` not `%02d`.

If you want the resolution to be at the tens of milliseconds level, then you'll have to do a little "fancy" calculating.

```
return String.format("%2d.%02d seconds", seconds, milliSeconds / 10);
```